# Passthrough/Temporary Variables in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm updating an ActiveAdmin page to keep up with a new feature I'm adding to my app, namely Google Sheets Integration. I need a way to capture user input (the auth code from google, copied and pasted from their site) so that I can use it do generate oAuth credentials for the account. I don't store the code in my database, only the credentials it generates.

How can I get this kind of input via ActiveAdmin? I have only ever seen it used to change database fields.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation for custom pages](https://activeadmin.info/10-custom-pages.html)  The [official documentation](https://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) and [wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki) have a lot of useful material.

Comment: From what I'm seeing there, the best option is to add a link and have the controller handle code generation. I'm still a little lost as to how I can return the code to form for the user to interact with, but I think I'm getting there.